# Check if a word in a string matches a word in an array and if so remove it from the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I was wondering if anybody could help, if I wanted to do a case insensitive check for if a word in a string matches a word in an array and if it did then remove that word from the string what would be the best method to do this?

Many thanks.

```
var testArray = new Array('that','from','again');

var testString = "It's That time again";
```

So in this example the words 'That' and 'again' would be removed from the string.

Comment: Can you share code you have tried to solve this?

Comment: The *best* method would likely be subjective

Comment: Loop your array, and simply remove that word from string. Like `testString.replace(testArray[i], '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string to filter the words from the string. Finally join them to get back the string:

```js
var testArray = new Array('that','from','again');
var testString = "It's That time again";

var resStr = testString.split(' ').filter(w => !testArray.includes(w.toLowerCase())).join(' ');
console.log(resStr);
```